# create reference to template virtual class c++

Tags: c++

I have such class

```
template<typename T>
    class ConnectionStatus:
    {
    public:

        virtual void setStatus(const T& status) = 0;
        virtual T getStatus() = 0;
    };
```

And i want to have a reference to this class in another class, so i do this: `ConnectionStatus<typename T>& status;` but compiler said `error: template argument 1 is invalid`. So how i can make a refernce to template virtual class?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main possibilities: when you know what that template argument should be for your class and when you don't.

For the former, it's a simple case of providing it (say it's `int` in this case):

```
struct MyClass
{
    ConnectionStatus<int> &m_connection_status;
};
```

If you don't know the argument, make your class a template class:

```
template <typename ConnectionStatusType>
struct MyClass
{
    ConnectionStatus<ConnectionStatusType> &m_connection_status;
};
```